# Freezing the value of type arguments in an inherited generic class

Tags: python, python-typing

```py
import typing as typ

T = typ.TypeVar("T")
X = typ.TypeVar("X")
class Base(typ.Generic[T, X]):
    pass

class ChildInt(?):
    pass

class InheritedInt(ChildInt[str]):
    # should be equivalent to Base[int, str]
```

I'd want to inherit `ChildInt` from `Base[int, ???]` where `ChildInt` is a generic that sets the `???` value.

**How do I achieve this?**

Comment: Something like `class ChildInt(Base[int, X]):`?

Comment: inheriting from `ChildInt[str]` gives out an error when I try that, i think.

Comment: Are you sure? MyPy only complains for me when I do something like `class InheritedInt(ChildInt[int, str]):`. Leads to `error: "ChildInt" expects 1 type argument, but 2 given  [type-arg]`.

Comment: `class ChildInt(Base[int, x])` is what you need, [certainly](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.10&gist=ea19d7f72cb543d284b5ccb03c9f67ef).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import typing as typ

T = typ.TypeVar("T")
X = typ.TypeVar("X")
class Base(typ.Generic[T, X]):
    pass

class ChildInt(Base[int, X]):
    pass

class InheritedInt(ChildInt[str]):
    # is equivalent to Base[int, str]
```

Comment: any idea on how to freeze the second typevar too? like inheriting from `Base[???, int]` instead

Comment: `class OtherChildInt(Base[T, int]):`

Note that it (almost) doesn't actually matter whether you use `T`, `X`, or a new TypeVar.